# returning a closeable iterable

Tags: java, java-6, iterable, finally

Suppose I have a lazy iterable instance which requires closing to free resources. If I return this from a method and close it in a finally block, will the finally block be invoked before or after it is consumed by the client?

For example:

```
public CloseableIterable<T> getStuff() {
    CloseableIterable<T> iterable = fetchStuffFromSomewhere();
    try {
        return iterable;
    } finally {
        iterable.close();
    }
}
```

Note: on Java 6 here, but I'd also be interested in how the try-with-resources bits in Java 7 would handle this case.

Comment: Why don't you try it? How could the finally block know that the client has finished using the returned value?

Comment: @JBNizet I have, and it appears to work (i.e. I can exhaust the iterator). But because the precise iterable type I get back is an abstract wrapper for several other things, I'm not sure if it works because the `close()` is just a dummy implementation which does nothing, and it'll fail on me in other circumstances.

Comment: Make it print "I'm closed', and check when "I'm closed" is printed. Or use your debugger to see when it's closed.

Comment: Typically, the method that creates the closeable would be responsible for closing it. In this case it looks like getStuff is just a wrapper to the factory or creator. Just let the method that calls getStuff close it. The only other way is to have getStuff iterate over it using a callback to pass values to the caller and figure out if the next one needs to be polled (if the callback indicates that it's done or hasNext returns false, close the thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` block will always execute before the `try` block is considered finished.

According to the [JLS, Section 14.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17), a return statement

> attempts to transfer control to the invoker of the method that contains it;

and

> *The preceding descriptions say "attempts to transfer control" rather than just "transfers control" because if there are any try statements (§14.20) within the method or constructor whose try blocks or catch clauses contain the return statement, **then any finally clauses of those try statements will be executed**, in order, innermost to outermost, before control is transferred to the invoker of the method or constructor. Abrupt completion of a finally clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a return statement.*

(**bold** emphasis mine)

That is, a `return` statement inside a `try` will execute the `finally` block before actually returning.  Therefore, your `CloseableIterable` will be closed before it gets returned to the caller.

As for "try-with-resources", the code is equivalent to a try-catch-finally block, so it should behave the same.  According to the [JLS, Section 14.20.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3),

> A try-with-resources statement is parameterized with variables (known as resources) that are initialized before execution of the try block and closed automatically, in the reverse order from which they were initialized, after execution of the try block.

That is, the equivalent code you've written above with "try-with-resources" in Java 1.7 would be:

```
try (CloseableIterable<T> iterable = fetchStuffFromSomewhere()) {
    return iterable;
}
```

... and it would still close it before control is transferred back to the method's caller.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block is executed right before the `return` statement. You will have to let the client code of the method handle the iterable instance correctly (make it part of your method contract and document it properly).

Also, it would be worth to learn by example. Go find a method in Java API that returns a `Closeable` and then go to its source code and see how it's handled.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) here:

```
public void forEachItemInStuff(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    CloseableIterable<T> iterable = fetchStuffFromSomewhere();
    try {
        for(T t:iterable) {
            consumer.accept(t);
        }
    } finally {
        iterable.close();
    }
}
```